# Running Time (Empty for loop vs for loop with one statement)

Tags: algorithm, loops, time, for-loop, performance

I have the following program and I am running it on VS 2010 Debug mode. To my surprise the empty for loop is taking more time than the for loop with addition statement. The time for empty for loop is 2371 ms and for addition for loop the time is 2043 ms. And I ran it several times and every single time empty for loop is faster. What is going on ?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    DWORD start = GetTickCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){

    }
    DWORD finish = GetTickCount();
    cout<<finish - start<<" ms."<<endl;


    start = GetTickCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
        int x = i + 1;
    }
    finish = GetTickCount();
    cout<<finish - start<<" ms."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Timing in debug mode is pretty unreliable. You can get an idea of the magnitude of performance, but it's pretty tough to get much better than that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Build your app with optimizations turned on.
2. Use a better timing method than GetTickCount, e.g. QueryPerformanceCounter
3. Detect context switches by measuring elapsed time often, and discarding abnormally large samples.

If you do the above, the two loops should take the same amount of time, since x is unused the compiler will likely just discard the statement entirely. Wouldn't be surprised if the loops were discarded in their entirety as well.

When measuring performance, use a profiler on real code.

Comment: +1 - Yes, I wouldn't be surprised to see the compiler optimize out both loops if x isn't used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is your time source.  The following VB code never executed the simple addition loop faster than the empty loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const loops As Integer = 100000000
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Dim precTM As Long = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp
    For x As Integer = 1 To loops
        'nothing
    Next
    precTM = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp - precTM

    ListBox1.Items.Add(precTM / Stopwatch.Frequency)
    ListBox1.Refresh()

    Dim foo As Integer
    precTM = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp
    For x As Integer = 1 To loops
        foo = x + 1
    Next

    precTM = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp - precTM
    ListBox1.Items.Add(precTM / Stopwatch.Frequency)


End Sub
```