# how to calculate total time taken by for loop

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

My Machine details :  32bit OS (win-7) ,  dual core , clock speed : 2.93Ghz , language used = c#

I have for loop

```
for ( long d = 0 d<= K  ; d++) 
{
    //no instrucitons
}
```

if K is any long number.

What would be the formula to calculate time required (in sec) to complete this loop ?

Comment: assume negligible other threads , processes on machine which  uses processor.

Comment: You mean without using a timer or stopwatch and running the program?

Comment: So assuming this is for a hard real-time system? Pretty much a non-question as C# can never fit that style. The GC could kick it at any point during and completely fluff up any calculations.

Comment: And BTW, the compiler/JIT-compiler will probably get rid of the whole loop if there's no instruction inside...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214850/running-time-empty-for-loop-vs-for-loop-with-one-statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214850/running-time-empty-for-loop-vs-for-loop-with-one-statement)

Comment: If you are really interested then use System.Diagnostics and use stopwatch class properties ( start and stop ) to calculate the time interval . But anyways it wont be of any use

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [Stopwatch.Elapsed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) of [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (long d = 0; d<= K; d++)   
        {      
        //do something  
        }         
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: He asked for the formula not the source.

Comment: Wow, I love how you dropped the OP's loop code in the middle of all that code but didn't bother to fix the `for` statement itself. (There's a missing semicolon after the initial-condition.)

Comment: Was more going for the stopwatch class, didn't pay much attention to the loop, fixed now.

Comment: i wanted to see how whats the impact of moving this code over to new machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile an empty loop, which has no side effects (which in your example case means that reading `K` has no side effects), then the execution time should be zero, since the compiler will optimize it out seeing it performs nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `stopwatch`

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.start();
for( long d = 0 d<= K  ; d++) 
{
    //dostuff
}
sw.stop()
debug.writeline(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```